# How to fix difference display of pseudo element between Macbook and Windows Desktop?

Tags: html, css

How do you do?
I have converted XD file to html, css code.
I checked on my PC(windows), but I didn't check on Macbook.
Details:
I coded button and used pseudo element to display right arrow at the right side.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<button class="register btn-top-register"><a href="#">Register</a></button>
```

CSS

```
.register{
    background-color: #FF6D1F;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 50px;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 5px 0px #8b3507;
}
.register::after{
    content: '\1F892';
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

This register button displayed triangle on Windows, but step shape on Macbook.
I tried many times to fix difference.

Could you help me how to fix and display the same shape-triangle?

Comment: can you share SS how does it look on windows I am using a mac so I can try to find the difference.

Comment: `<a>` inside a `<button>` , is not a good idea and is invalid : https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element . *Content model:
    Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) to test your code in different devices such as mac and ios

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these unicodes https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/.

If you want to use of unicode I don't know exactly.

I suggest you to use SVG or img to display an icon on your button.
You can download an SVG icon from [flatiIcon](https://www.flaticon.com/), or you can use of [featherIcon](https://feathericons.com/) or [font awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) for example.